# QPython or Kivy for a COMPLETE Noob to Design a Display on Android?

Tags: android, kivy, qpython

So as the title hints at, I am in fact a complete Noob at this.  I've been doing a lot of reading, and I still can't decide which package to use.  What I'm trying to do is pretty simple - just have the display to flash different patterns of colors on a tablet device for a set period of time.  I'm not going to put this on the Playstore. Kivy sounds like the way to go, but then I have to create a virtual machine that runs on Linux and what not.  Side note:  What is an APK!?!?!
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An APK is an Android app package, you can just google this.

For your requirement to modify the display, you can use Kivy within qpython if you don't mind loading the script from within the app, or build your own Kivy APK if you want the functionality to be in a standalone app.

Comment: So would Kivy and Qpython replace the Android SDK tool for Android development?  If so, would I need additional packages?